# ¿Como obtener los datos que estén entre dos fechas?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos en Mysql donde tengo un campo fecha del tipo character varchar  con formato `m/d/Y`, lo que quiero obtener son todas las filas que se encuentren entre dos fechas dadas por ejemplo :`'03/04/2017'`y `'07/04/2017'`

```
select 
    * 
from 
    table 
where 
    fecha between '03/04/2017' and '07/04/2017'
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para obtener los datos que necesito?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu campo de fecha está como tipo `varchar` entonces al hacer tu comparación MySQL no sabe que estás comparando fechas, lo que tendrías que hacer es cambiar tu tipo de dato de la columna ya sea a `DATE` o `DATETIME` para que así el motor pueda hacer la consulta con el rango de fechas que estás buscando.

Este es un ejemplo muy vago pero te ejemplificará a lo que me refiero:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/805021/2

```
create table datos(
  fecha DATE
);

insert into datos (fecha) values ('2012-01-02');
insert into datos (fecha) values ('2012-01-03');
insert into datos (fecha) values ('2012-01-04');
insert into datos (fecha) values ('2012-01-05');
insert into datos (fecha) values ('2012-01-06');

select 
    * 
from 
    datos
where 
    fecha between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-03';
```

También toma en cuenta que en MySQL debe de ser el formato de fecha YYY-MM-DD, mostrarlo en el orden M/D/Y lo puedes hacer con el mismo lenguaje de MySQL u otro lenguaje de programación